# How to enable sound effects for a Button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"` for a button in layout.xml file.

In Settings, I have enabled the sound effects and I can hear the effect in default apps but not in my app. Is there anything I have to do other than this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sound effects enabled for onClick() method, but not for onTouch().
What method you used? if it was onTouch(), use such thing:

```
v.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mamacita_one);
            }
        });
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent ev) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mamacita_zero);
            mp.start();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, ev);

}
```

or u can refer

[Creating Sound Effects in Android](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html)

Comment: Link in answer is dead.